# Xcode Auto suggestion and Indexing Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode9.1

Indexing not working in My Xcode Project and also not got Auto suggestion list. does any one know how to resolve this issue?

I am using Xcode 9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

goto xcode
Preferences(Command+,)
Text Editing tab
Editing tab
Code completion
Check suggest completions while typing

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps:

1. Simply Go to **Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing**
2. Under **Code completion - Uncheck 'Suggest completions while typing'**
3. Quit out of `Xcode` and then relaunch `Xcode`.
4. Go to **Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing again**
5. Quit out of `Xcode` and then relaunch `Xcode`.
6. Now go to Code completion and check **'Suggest completions while typing'**.
7. Try typing any library function.